# Specify JsonSerializerOptions for HttpResults in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

With ASP.NET Core MVC, it's possible to return a result by multiple ways.

[Controller action return types in ASP.NET Core web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types) :

- Specific type
- `IActionResult`
- ...
- `HttpResult`

But when the controller action returns `HttpResult`, ASP.NET Core MVC serialization options are ignored.

**Example**

`Program.cs`:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(
    o => o.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = System.Text.Json.JsonNamingPolicy.SnakeCaseUpper
);
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

`FoosController.cs`:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpResults;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication.Controllers;

[Route("foos")]
public class FoosController
{
    [HttpGet("raw")]
    public Foo Raw() => new Foo();

    [HttpGet("action-result")]
    public IActionResult Action() => new OkObjectResult(new Foo());

    [HttpGet("http-result")]
    public IResult Http() => Results.Ok(new Foo());

    [HttpGet("typed-result")]
    public Ok<Foo> Typed() => TypedResults.Ok(new Foo());
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; } = "";
}
```

The endpoints `/raw` and `/action-result` return :

```json
{
  "ID": 0,
  "LABEL": ""
}
```

But the endpoints `/http-result` and `/typed-result` return :

```json
{
  "id": 0,
  "label": ""
}
```

How can I specify serialization options for `HttpResult`?

Comment: Well based on your scenario and description, I would like to inform you that,  the `HttpResult` type in ASP.NET Core is designed to allow more control over the response without relying on the built-in serialization options. However, if you want to apply specific serialization options to the content of an HttpResult, you can achieve this by manually serializing the content before creating the HttpResult. In that case, you can create a custom output formatter that utilizes desired `JsonSerializerOptions`

Comment: `TypedResults` is convenient, because the action method signature describes the possibility of HTTP status return. It's ensure the endpoint return that is expected, unlike `IActionResult`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MCV** has [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.JsonOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.jsonoptions) to configure serialization options, **HttpResult** has [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Json.JsonOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.json.jsonoptions).

You can configure serialization options for **HttpResult** like :

```cs
builder.Services.Configure<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Json.JsonOptions>(
    o => o.SerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = System.Text.Json.JsonNamingPolicy.SnakeCaseUpper
);
```

---

Trick to mutualise the configuration of serialization options between **MVC** and **HttpResult** :

```cs
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(
    o => o.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = System.Text.Json.JsonNamingPolicy.SnakeCaseUpper
);
builder.Services.AddSingleton(p =>
{
    var mOpt = p.GetRequiredService<IOptions<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.JsonOptions>>().Value;
    var hOpt = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Json.JsonOptions();
    hOpt.SerializerOptions.AllowTrailingCommas = mOpt.JsonSerializerOptions.AllowTrailingCommas;
    hOpt.SerializerOptions.DefaultBufferSize = mOpt.JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultBufferSize;
    hOpt.SerializerOptions.NumberHandling = mOpt.JsonSerializerOptions.NumberHandling;
    hOpt.SerializerOptions.PreferredObjectCreationHandling = mOpt.JsonSerializerOptions.PreferredObjectCreationHandling;
    hOpt.SerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = mOpt.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive;
    hOpt.SerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = mOpt.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy;
    hOpt.SerializerOptions.ReadCommentHandling = mOpt.JsonSerializerOptions.ReadCommentHandling;
    hOpt.SerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = mOpt.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler;
    hOpt.SerializerOptions.TypeInfoResolver = mOpt.JsonSerializerOptions.TypeInfoResolver;
    hOpt.SerializerOptions.UnknownTypeHandling = mOpt.JsonSerializerOptions.UnknownTypeHandling;
    hOpt.SerializerOptions.UnmappedMemberHandling = mOpt.JsonSerializerOptions.UnmappedMemberHandling;
    hOpt.SerializerOptions.WriteIndented = mOpt.JsonSerializerOptions.WriteIndented;
    hOpt.SerializerOptions.TypeInfoResolverChain.Clear();
    mOpt.JsonSerializerOptions.TypeInfoResolverChain.ToList().ForEach(r => hOpt.SerializerOptions.TypeInfoResolverChain.Add(r));
    hOpt.SerializerOptions.Converters.Clear();
    mOpt.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.ToList().ForEach(c => hOpt.SerializerOptions.Converters.Add(c));
    return Options.Create(hOpt);
});
```

Have to think about adapting it to each evolution of `JsonSerializerOptions`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's by design that the `HttpResults` setup doesn't play along with the configured formatters and their settings (here: the JsonSerializationOptions).

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-8.0#httpresults-type):

> Different than the MVC-specific result types, the HttpResults:
> Does not leverage the configured Formatters.
>
> Not leveraging the configured formatters means:
> Some features like Content negotiation aren't available.

---

One way to handle this for the `IResult` setup is to call [`Results.Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.results.json?view=aspnetcore-8.0) or [`TypedResults.Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.typedresults.json?view=aspnetcore-8.0) with the appropriate serialization options and optional content type and http status code.

```
[Route("foos")]
public class FoosController
{
    private static readonly JsonSerializerOptions _jsonSerializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.SnakeCaseUpper
    };

    [HttpGet("http-result")]
    public IResult Http()
        => Results.Json(new Foo(), _jsonSerializerOptions);
        // or
        // => TypedResults.Json(new Foo(), _jsonSerializerOptions);
}
```

Comment: It isn't possible to override serialization options for `HttpResult`?

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be creating a custom `ActionResult` that inherits from `ObjectResult` or `ActionResult<T>`, allowing you to apply serialization settings.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure;

public class CustomJsonResult : ObjectResult
{
   public CustomJsonResult(object value)
    : base(value)
  {
     this.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status200OK;
     this.SerializerSettings = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings
     {
        // Apply your serialization settings here
        ContractResolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver
        {
            NamingStrategy = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.SnakeCaseNamingStrategy()
        },
        Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented
        // Add more settings as needed
      };
   }
}
```

Then, you can use this custom result type in your controller:

```
[HttpGet("http-result")]
public IActionResult Http()
 {
  var foo = new Foo();
  return new CustomJsonResult(foo);
 }
```

Comment: Thank, I learn something interesting. But the question is about `HttpResult`, not `ActionResult`.